# LogTarget is logging messages written in the log

Tags: logging, ibm-datapower

I have created a log target to the messages and errors. 
I am getting all info messages are logged in it and push to file system.

I am able to see the message added XSLT in system log. But not able to see in file system 
Any help?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to choose 'xsltmsg' in logtarget